# Getting <textarea> value with jQuery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are quire a few "jQuery getting element value" questions on here, but I was unable to find one that helped in my situation. Please read before marking as a duplicate, although I am  more than happyto be pointed to another question which successfully answers my question.

I have the following `<textarea>`

```
<textarea id="comment_text" class="comment" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Comment...'; nocomLeft() }" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Comment...') { this.value = ''; comLeft() }">Comment...</textarea>
```

This adds placeholder text, removes it when it has focus, and adds it backs again if nothing is entered.

Now at various points, like when I click a button, I do:

```
var comment = $('#comment_text').text();
```

Which no matter what returns the value `Comment...` even if I have typed in the text area, clicked somewhere else to remove the focus, and can clearly see my new text still in the text area - `$('#comment_text').text()' always comes back`Comment...`

I am stumped, all help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/auGpN/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.val()`

```
$('#comment_text').val();
```

Also, save some JS, and use the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: Scratch that... I'm lying, using .val does indeed work. I will leave this question here as a reminder of my stupidity.

Comment: To clarify this answer, "The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method." http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) would be the proper method to call. So in your example, it would be
 `var comment = $('#comment_text').val();`

Note that you can even set the text of the textarea by doing something like
 `var comment = $('#comment_text').val('this is a test');`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.val()` method

`$('#comment_text').val();`